AWS: How to obtain the RoleSessionName while trying to assume a role Boto3
I want to connect to a bucket across account by assuming a role that has access to that bucket.
client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_role = client.assume_role(RoleArn=settings.iam_role_arn, RoleSessionName='sessionname',DurationSeconds=900)

Where could one get sessionname in runtime?

You can create any role session name you wish. It is used to track that particular assumption of the role. See: assume_role - Boto3 documentation
